# Displaying files from document library using powerapps canvas app

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to design PowerApps canvas app to display below files from Sampletest document library and when user click on the files from each folders but then I also need to restrict access for each files and they would not be able to download unless they get approval from admin users

so my query here is how to design the below structure and manage unique permissions for each folders at PowerApps level. since user will be able to download the file only if admin approve the request to download for each file as soon as approver approves then user can download the file from PowerApps

Kindly help

[image]

[image]
[image]
Below is my canvas app and I am able to fetch items from document library and display as below but i need help on how to allow user to download files based on Admin approvers list.

so my query here is if user logged in and clicks on download icon then notify to admin approvers list for the selected file and if approver approves for the selected file item then user got access to download file so below download icon should have access to download

[image]
[image]
User should able to launch the file item if approvers from admin approvers list approves that request for selected file item, as of now it launches file item but I should restrict this based on approvers decision for any file in that document library(Sampletest) .We using Msflow for on clicking the download icon request for access for selected file item but how to check if approver approved that file in the PowerApps level.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If access is restricted, users will not be able to see these documents,so there is currently no way to achieve the function of obtaining the approval of the administrator and otherwise it will not be possible to download.

Thank you for your understanding and support.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.